# How to install a jQueryMobile project into smartphones with Convertigo?

Tags: jquery-mobile, convertigo

When I finish creating a `jQueryMobile` project with `Convertigo` , how to proceed to install the project inside a smartphone so that it becomes like a native `app` ?

Comment: Hi pheromix, I used to do this a few weeks ago, can you add details about the platforms you are targeting?

Comment: The targeting platforms are Android and Windows 8 tablet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How to generate:**

For building your apps, you have to access the admin console of your local server (installed with the development platform) and perform a few steps.

- First, don't forget to set the `application ID` (on your Studio, in your application project
  parameters) and the `application endpoint`
- Connect to your Convertigo admin page on your local Studio: `localhost:18080/convertigo/admin`
- In the projects tab, choose your mobile project, then click on the platform you want to build and you will have a button to generate the application. Once generated, you can click on the QRCode to download the file (for example the apk for Android).

---

**Info about the admin console:** [See Convertigo doc here](http://help.convertigo.com/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.twinsoft.convertigo.studio.help%2Fhelp%2FhelpOperatingGuide%2F421Configurationpage.html)

---

**About the build:**

Convertigo Studio uses PhoneGap Build in background. By default you use a Convertigo account, but you will have to use your account to build release apps, because you will have to sign them with your own certificates.

> The Convertigo mobile builder platform performs mobile application
>   build thanks to PhoneGap build platform. Once a PhoneGap build account
>   is configured thanks to the Mobile builder authentication token, do
>   not forget to configure all mobile platforms certificates and keys in
>   accordance. Find below the documentation of properties that need to be
>   filled for mobile platforms certificates and keys.

If you use your own account, you just have to set up the `Mobile builder authentication token` in the admin console:

> Mobile builder authentication token: This property defines the
>   authentication token of the Mobile builder account to use to build the
>   mobile application. The Mobile builder account is nothing more than a
>   PhoneGap build account. It is referenced now by an authentication
>   token. When building a mobile application, a Mobile builder account
>   (PhoneGap build account) is mandatory. Convertigo provides one by
>   default, used by default in Convertigo engine. This Mobile builder
>   authentication token property allows you to define your own Mobile
>   builder authentication token. It will be used by default for all
>   mobile applications built by the Convertigo. It can still be
>   overridden by the Mobile builder authentication token property in each
>   Mobile application object in Convertigo projects.

Comment: absolutely, i will edit right now! Is the description clear? In fact for debug process on Android you just need to generate the apk from the web interface. I'm not sure for Windows, maybe you need to provide a developer certificate first (and create your own phonegap build account to use it)